# HasMany Relation through BelongsToMany Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to make Laravel relation through belongsToMany relations?

I have 4 tables:

1)Restaurants (id , name) - uses hasManyRelation with Workers table

2)Directors (id , name)

3)Directors_Restaurants (id, director_id, restaurant_id) - pivot table for connecting belongsToMany Restaurants with Directors

3)Workers (id, name, restaurant_id)

With this function in Directors model i can get all connected restaurants

```
public function restaurants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Restaurant','director_restaurant');
}
```

With this function in my code i can get all workers of all restaurants of one director

```
$director = Director::find(1);
$director->load('restaurants.workers');
$workers = $director->restaurants->pluck('workers')->collapse();
```

So my question is : can i declare similar relation in my Director model to get all its workers of all its restaurants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can suggest a solution like this:

**Director Model OPTION 1**

```
public function getAllRestaurants(){
    return $this->hasMany(Restaurant::class)->with('restaurants.workers');
}
```

**Director Model OPTION 2**

```
public function getAllRestaurants(){
    $this->load('restaurants.workers');
    return $this->restaurants->pluck('workers')->collapse();
}
```

**You can get all restaurants anywhere**

```
$all_restaurants = Director::find(1)->getAllRestaurants();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, OPTION2 is exactly what i need. One more question: with  function 'load(something.othersomething)' a can refer any relation in my model? Even refer one relation from another?

Comment: Yes you can refer to any relation of your model. Just make sure that all foreign keys are setup well.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can have `hasMany` relationship method on Director model with [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

just like below

```
public function restaurants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Restaurant::class)->with('restaurants.workers');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

## You can define an `accessor` method in your model to hide some of the logic

```php
# App/Director.php

// You'll need this line if you want this attribute to appear when you call toArray() or toJson()
// If not, you can comment it
protected $appends = ['workers'];

public function getWorkersAttribute()
{
    return $this->restaurants->pluck('workers')->collapse();
}

# Somewhere else
$director = Director::with('restaurants.workers')->find(1);
$workers = $director->workers;
```

But ultimately, you still have to load the nested relationship `'restaurants.workers'` for it to work.

## Given your table attributes you could also define a custom `HasMany` relationship that looks like this

```php
# App/DirectorRestaurant.php

public function workers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Worker::class, 'restaurant_id', 'restaurant_id');
}

# Somewhere else
$director = Director::find(1);
$workers = DirectorRestaurant::where('director_id', $director->id)->get()->each(function($q) { $q->load('workers'); });
```

But I don't recommend it because it's not very readable.

Lastly, there's the `staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep` package where you can define that sort of nested relationship.

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Answer (score 0):

You can define a direct relationship by "skipping" the `restaurants` table:

```php
class Director extends Model
{
    public function workers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Worker::class,
            'director_restaurant',
            'director_id', 'restaurant_id', null, 'restaurant_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but got "BelongsToMany could not be converted to string" exception.

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: this way: $director = Director::find($id); return $director->workers();

Comment: Use `return $director->workers;` or `return $director->workers()->get();`: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations